# How do I insert a new line before concatenating?

Tags: linux, file, unix, command-line, ubuntu

I have about 80000 files which I am trying to concatenate. This one:

```
cat files_*.raw >> All
```

is extremely fast whereas the following:

```
for f in `ls files_*.raw`; do cat $f >> All; done;
```

is extremely slow. Because of this reason, I am trying to stick with the first option except that I need to be able to insert a new line after each file is concatenated to `All`. Is there any fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
ls files_*.raw | xargs -L1 sed -e '$s/$/\n/' >>ALL
```

That will insert an extra newline at the end of each file as you concat them.

And a parallel version if you don't care about the order of concatenation:

```
find ./ -name "*.raw" -print | xargs -n1 -P4 sed -e '$s/$/\n/' >>All
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. I added a parallel version as well just in case. Thank you.

Comment: be careful of parallizing this, as you output would be intermingled in the ALL-file -- not sure if you care about that or not.

Comment: Actually, that should be fine because I am extracting some stats about individual files and order does not matter in this case. In an unrelated case, I have no idea why the answer was downvoted without a comment!

Comment: +1 for the good answer, too bad I can't do another to compensate for the mystery downvote.  Downvoter - please comment!

Comment: @Legend - re your parallel version: if you're going to use `find | xargs` you should (almost?) always use the NUL terminating options `find .... -print0 | xargs -0 ....` so you don't break if there are any files or directories with spaces in their names.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I am using that. I forgot to type it here :) Thanks for the tip in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The second command might be slow because you are opening the 'All' file for append 80000 times vs. 1 time in the first command. Try a simple variant of the second command:

```
for f in `ls files_*.raw`; do cat $f ; echo '' ; done >> All
```

Comment: If you really want to use a for loop like that (which has limitation on the number of files which can be processed) then at least get rid of the `ls`  and also make sure you quote your file names, so:  

`for f in files_*.raw; do cat "$f" ; echo '' ; done >> All`

Comment: +1 Thank you for your efforts but I had this version already but as Soren mentioned, I had to avoid `ls` altogether along with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it would be slow, but I don't think you have much choice:

```
for f in `ls files_*.raw`; do cat $f >> All; echo '' >> All; done
```

Comment: +1 for your time. Like I mentioned in other comments, I was trying to avoid a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Each time awk opens another file to process, the FRN equals 0, so:

```
awk '(0==FRN){print ""} {print}' files_*.raw >> All
```

Note, it's all done in one awk process. Performance should be close to the cat command from the question.